# SQL Datepart (week), ORDER BY year?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datepart

I use this following query here to get my data and show the value weekly, however, when there is a new year and the result will show week `50, 51, 52 of 2016` and week `1, 2, 3 of 2017` for example, it will `order by` week number resulting in `1,2,3,50,51,52` which means that the 2017 results appear before 2016, how do I change this?

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(wk, date) AS number,
    SUM((kg * rep * sett)) AS weight,
    SUM(kg / max * rep * sett) AS avg,
    SUM((rep * sett)) AS reps,
    MAX(kg / max) AS peak
FROM
    Test
WHERE
    date BETWEEN @0 AND @1 AND exercise < 4
GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, date)
```

Comment: Your query does not contain an order by clause...

Comment: What should I order by? because date didn't work :/ @ZoharPeled

Comment: It depends on possible `@0 AND @1` span. Can it span jan2015 to jan 2017 and what you want as a result being it the case?

Comment: You should add the datepart(year) to the group by, the select and the order by clause should contain both date parts.

Comment: well it should be ordered by year, even if multiple week number 5 for example @Serg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, but you could just include the year in the field you group by:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(year, date)) + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(wk, date)) AS Year_Week,
    SUM((kg * rep * sett)) AS weight,
    SUM(kg / max * rep * sett) AS avg,
    SUM((rep * sett)) AS reps,
    MAX(kg / max) AS peak
FROM
    Test
WHERE
    date BETWEEN @0 AND @1 AND exercise < 4
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(year, date)) + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(wk, date))
ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(year, date)) + '_' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(wk, date))
```

or (probably better), just treat them as entirely separate fields:

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(year, date) AS Year,
    DATEPART(wk, date) AS Week,
    SUM((kg * rep * sett)) AS weight,
    SUM(kg / max * rep * sett) AS avg,
    SUM((rep * sett)) AS reps,
    MAX(kg / max) AS peak
FROM
    Test
WHERE
    date BETWEEN @0 AND @1 AND exercise < 4
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, date), DATEPART(wk, date)
ORDER BY DATEPART(year, date), DATEPART(wk, date)
```

Comment: gave me this error `There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 37,Token in error = DATEPART ]` on your last example! what could that be?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?

Comment: Sql server compact

Comment: @Serg thanks, corrected. Was confused by the SQL Compact version of the error - might have recognised `Incorrect syntax near 'DATEPART'.` if it had been run via SSMS. :)

Comment: haha completely missed that comma! Thanks for the help, this works excellent! Really appreciate it!

Comment: You deserved it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add an order by on aggregate of year part:

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(wk, date) AS number,
    SUM((kg * rep * sett)) AS weight,
    SUM(kg / max * rep * sett) AS avg,
    SUM((rep * sett)) AS reps,
    MAX(kg / max) AS peak
FROM
    Test
WHERE
    date BETWEEN @0 AND @1 AND exercise < 4
GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, date)
order by max(datepart(year,date)), number;
```

The above however aggregate together data from same week number, even if they fall in different year (Probably not what you want). If you want to keep the different years' data separate, you can for example add an year column to your output.

```
SELECT 
    datepart(year,date) as year,
    DATEPART(wk, date) AS number,
    SUM((kg * rep * sett)) AS weight,
    SUM(kg / max * rep * sett) AS avg,
    SUM((rep * sett)) AS reps,
    MAX(kg / max) AS peak
FROM
    Test
WHERE
    date BETWEEN @0 AND @1 AND exercise < 4
GROUP BY datepart(year,date), DATEPART(wk, date)
order by year, number;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still group records from different years together if they fell on the same week within their respective years?